# Angular2 Browser History Navigation

Tags: angular

How to navigate to previous state and back in the browser history.

I remember AngularJS supported this:

```
$window.history.back();
```

React supports this:

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'
browserHistory.goBack();
```

How to back and previous browser history in Angular 2 >= v2.1.0

Comment: `window.history.back()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use built in Location service, which has back api.

Sample code-

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Location} from '@angular/common';


@Component({ .... })
class AppComponent {
    constructor(private _location: Location) {
    }
    backClicked() {
        this._location.back();
    }
}
```

Reference: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/Location-class.html

See if this helps.